# Interface as one used for inheritance reasons, not implementors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

Interface in .NET is actually compiled into class, pure abstract class with only difference of having the **interface** prefix on it. So in general, any implementor of interface turns out to be the inheritor of that interface, not implementor as written in many books. Yes, I know that interface serves another purpose in enterprise code - to give common capability to unrelated classes. But to MSIL any class is actually sub-type of interface. It gives a reason to just extend interface with simple concrete classes, not to make another derived interface of the base interface. So when some client has reference to the interface and there is a need to downcast to more specific entity, developers make another derived interface and downcast to it. Why they don't practive downcasting directly to concrete derived class as it's actually a valid sub-type of interface??
Example code:

```
public inteface IEntity
{
     int Id { get; set; } 
}

public class Vote : IEntity 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int SubjectId { get; set; }

     public bool Sign { get; set;}

     public int UserId {get; set;} 

     public void Validate() 
     {
         if (UserId == default)
            throw new Exception("UserId is not defined");
         if (SubjectId == default)
            throw new Exception("SubjectId is not defined");
     }
}

public abstract class BusinessEngine
{
     private readonly IRepository _repo;

      public void Save(IEntity entity) 
      {
          BeforeSave(entity);
          DoSave(entity); // omit code, it just delegates work to repository
          AfterSave();
      }

      protected virtual void BeforeSave(IEntity entity) 
      {
      }

      protected virtual void AfterSave(IEntity entity) 
      {
      }
} 

public class VotesBE: BusinessEngine
{
      protected override void BeforeSave(IEntity entity) 
      {
            var vote = entity as Vote;
            vote.Validate();
      }
}
```

But many developers would prefer to make another derived interface to `IEntity` - say, the `IValidatableEntity` that would extend the base `IEntity` interface and they would do this thing in code of BusinessEngine:

```
`public abstract class BusinessEngine
{
     private readonly IRepository _repo;

      public void Save(IEntity entity) 
      {
          BeforeSave(entity);
          DoSave(entity); // omit code, it just delegates work to repository
          AfterSave();
      }

      protected virtual void BeforeSave(IEntity entity) 
      {
        if (entity is IValidatableEntity ve)
              ve.Validate();
      }

      protected virtual void AfterSave(IEntity entity) 
      {
      }
}`
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say with "So when some client has reference to the interface and there is a need to downcast to more specific entity, developers make another derived interface and downcast to it.". Do you have some specific example of something you want to show us here?

Comment: I added a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both techniques you describe are valid, however your proposed technique would probably be implemented with [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

For example:

```cs
public abstract class BusinessEngine<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
     private readonly IRepository _repo;

      public void Save(TEntity entity) 
      {
          var typedEntity = entity as TEntity;

          BeforeSave(entity);
          DoSave(entity);
          AfterSave();
      }

      protected virtual void BeforeSave(TEntity entity) { }

      protected virtual void AfterSave(TEntity entity) { }
}
```

```cs
public class VoteBusinessEngine : BusinessEngine<Vote>
{
      protected override void BeforeSave(Vote entity) 
      {
            vote.Validate();
      }
}
```

Now, to your original question of "why do it one way over the other?" It depends on your goals and needs.

If your goal is to write a general-purpose service (or collection of services) that can handle many types of entities, you probably want the `IValidatableEntity` approach. In that case, you're letting the entities describe their capabilities by implementing additional interfaces.

If you want to add special-case handling to a single service for just a few entity types without modifying the entities themselves, then the Generic approach makes sense.

It really comes down to: Who do you want to "own" the special behavior? The entity or the service?

If you want to go deeper, read about [Role Interfaces](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) and the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (the 'I' in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).